# Why Tagfield in ExtJs 5.1 always return blank for getDisplayValue()?

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs5

I am using `tagfiled` in my `extjs 5.1.0` Application.I just caught in issue with `tagfield` that I never get display value.

There is no issue for getting value from `tagfield`, but I'm unable to get display value.

> Method I'm using for getting display value from tagfield is
>   `getDisplayValue()`

Please find fiddle here [Tagfiled getDisplayValue() Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pn7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug in 5.1.0 fixed in 5.1.1.

The `tagfield`'s method `getDisplayValue()` simply returns `getRawValue()`. The latter is implemented differently in [5.1.0](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/source/Tag.html#Ext-form-field-Tag-method-getRawValue) (the one you are using) and say [5.1.1](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/source/Tag.html#Ext-form-field-Tag-method-getRawValue) (in which your fiddle works fine). Switch your fiddle to 5.1.1 and see.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this problem would be to use the code shown below.

```
    listeners:{
        select: function(record){ 
            var activeRecord = this.getStore().findRecord(this.valueField,this.getValue());
            var actualValue = this.getValue();  
            var displayValue = activeRecord.get(this.displayField);
            console.log('combo value',actualValue);
            console.log('combo display value',displayValue);
        }
    }
```